# Identify which cell in a row contains a specific text

Tags: excel

I have a column compromising of text, I would like to search through that entire column to identify in which cell does the contents contain text that I am searching for.

[Snip of the excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7igL.png)

I need to search for the text in the first column and identify which cell in the final column contains the data I am searching for.

Comment: use `vlookup()`

Comment: Please explain the same from the screenshots

Comment: Ok no problem.

I want to check if the text "00156204" in cell A1 is a subset of the text in F1 "confirmed order progressed..".

If A1 is not a substring of F1, it should check if A1 is a substring F2 etc 

If A1 is a substring of the F cell, it should identify what F cell contains the text.

Answer (score 0):

You use this formula,

=IfError(VLOOKUP (A2, A2:D25, 3,False),"")

This formula will search for value match with A2 in data range A2:D25, in Column 3 means in C,, if find pull the match otherwise return a Blank. U can write "Value not found" within quotes also.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I dont think i was clear in posting my question. Let me try explaining again.

The search text in A1, I need to tell if it is a substring of any text in the lookup range.

If it is a substring, I would like the cell it is a substring of to be identified.

Comment: If you want to find String within string neither Search or Find work for that, both only returns Position,, better use this, 

=Mid(B9, 7,6) here it pull substring from B9, which starts from 7th & total character to find 6.

Or =MID (B9, Search (" ", B9) +1,6)

Find 6 characters long text in B9 starts after First Blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula in some column , say I,

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$1,F1,1)),"",F1)
```

Drag down till the end of list. This will return what all matches A1 with column F. If you want to search for A2, change the formula to A2 and do the same. This cannot be done for all columns in A with all columns with F as there is a chance that the same string can be found in one or more cells in F.